# Detail View of a CoreData list item in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass the details of a CoreData list item on to a separate detail view...

My Item Model

```
class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedEntites: [MemoryEntity] = []
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MemoryContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
              print("Error loading CoreData. \(error)")
        }
        }
        FetchMemories()
    }
    
    func FetchMemories() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<MemoryEntity>(entityName: "MemoryEntity")
        do {
        savedEntites = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching \(error)")
        }
    }   
   
    }
```

My content View

```
                   @StateObject var vm = CoreDataViewModel()

                   List {
                        ForEach(vm.savedEntites) { entity in
                            Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                                
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {showingDetailScreen.toggle()}) {
                                Label("View Details", systemImage: "pencil")
                                         }.foregroundColor(Color(.red))
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetailScreen) {
                                    DetailItemView(isVisible: self.$showingDetailScreen, entity: entity)
                                       }    
                            }
                        }
```

Detail View, this is where i want details of the item to be shown. For now i just want the "name" to be displayed on this view.

```
struct DetailItemView: View  {
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        @Binding var isVisible: Bool
        var entity: MemoryEntity
 
        var body: some View {
            Text("\(entity.name)")
            HStack {
            Button("Exit") {
                self.isVisible = false
                   }
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
            }
    }
```

...But i'm getting this error in DetailItemView right next to `Text("\(entity.name)")`:

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all creating a string from a string with String Interpolation is redundant.

Secondly your code already includes the answer (right after `ForEach`). As `name` is an optional you have to unwrap it.

```
Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

in DetailItemView do what you did in ContentView use:

```
Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")
```